# Translations single page application

Tags: javascript, configuration, internationalization, single-page-application

I'm building multilingual SPA.
Is there a best practice what is the best way to load translations?

Should they be loaded:

1. from remote end point that has all translations
2. from remote end point only translation that you require
3. inline translations file in index.html
4. add translations to the rest of js in compile time (webpack)
5. something else

Comment: That really depends on your application. Do you have only two or many different languages? Do you only have a couple of texts or thousands? Does your app need to work offline? Do you have only some or many different routes? Do you do server-side rendering?

Comment: I have 4 languages, each language has its own domain that points to the same server. For now it has moderate number of text, but might grow to thousands. App does not need to work offline. There are 5 routes right now, but again it might grow. For now there is no server side rendering, and again depending on project success we might have to move to all these `buts`. However, `buts` are not going to happen for at least year or two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular do check their i18n approach. Angular core team are working on things like dynamic translation but it has things that you need to make your application localize. This approach would also give you a better performance than the traditional data-driven approach where you switch the json files based on the language selected during run time.